# ModSecurity whitelist my IP, false positive on response body due to gzip?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php

How can I whitelist my IP address on modsecurity or just completely ignore the response body so it stops tripping like this?

I have my wordpress site behind cloudflare.
My site also uses a cache plugin.

This is my configuration on my vhost config file.

```bsh
<IfModule mod_security3.c>
    modsecurity on
    modsecurity_rules_file '/etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.d/rules.conf'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecAuditLog /var/log/httpd/example.net-modsecurity.log'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecAuditLogParts ABCEFHZ'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecDefaultAction "phase:1,nolog,auditlog,pass"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecDefaultAction "phase:2,nolog,auditlog,pass"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecResponseBodyAccess Off'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch <MY_IP_ADDRESS>" "id:20210410001,phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch <MY_IP_ADDRESS>" "id:20210410002,phase:2,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch <MY_IP_ADDRESS>" "id:20210410003,phase:3,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch <MY_IP_ADDRESS>" "id:20210410004,phase:4,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"'
</IfModule>
```

This part

```bsh
    modsecurity_rules 'SecResponseBodyAccess Off'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly'
```

seems to be ignored because it's still tripping with

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?:\x1f\x8b\x08|\b(?:(?:i(?:nterplay|hdr|d3)|m(?:ovi|thd)|r(?:ar!|iff)|(?:ex|jf)if|f(?:lv|ws)|varg|cws)\b|gif)|B(?:%pdf|\.ra)\b|^wOF[F2])' against variable `RESPONSE_BODY' (Value: `\xff\xcd!>}\xbbG\xf1\x1cN'\xb6I\x0e\xa6\xfas\x0e2Z\x8e\xf9\xf29\x0a\x0e\x84a|\xac\xd4Vo\xd6\x99n\xd0 (23587 characters omitted)' ) [file "/usr/local/coreruleset/rules/RESPONSE-953-DATA-LEAKAGES-PHP.conf"] [line "83"] [id "953120"] [rev ""] [msg "PHP source code leakage"] [data "Matched Data: <? found within RESPONSE_BODY: \xff\xcd!>}\xbbG\xf1\x1cN'\xb6I\x0e\xa6\xfas\x0e2Z\x8e\xf9\xf29\x0a\x0e\x84a|\xac\xd4Vo\xd6\x99n\xd0 (7941 characters omitted)"] [severity "3"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-php"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-disclosure"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/118/116"] [tag "PCI/6.5.6"] [hostname "example.net"] [uri "/wp-admin/post.php"] [unique_id "1618055573"] [ref "o4271,2v2196,8096v2196,8096"]
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 200 (phase 4). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `4' against variable `TX:OUTBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `4' ) [file "/usr/local/coreruleset/rules/RESPONSE-959-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "68"] [id "959100"] [rev ""] [msg "Outbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 4)"] [data ""] [severity "0"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "anomaly-evaluation"] [hostname "example.net"] [uri "/wp-admin/post.php"] [unique_id "1618055573"] [ref ""]
```

And these rules

```bsh
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch <MY_IP_ADDRESS>" "id:20210410001,phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch <MY_IP_ADDRESS>" "id:20210410002,phase:2,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch <MY_IP_ADDRESS>" "id:20210410003,phase:3,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch <MY_IP_ADDRESS>" "id:20210410004,phase:4,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"'
```

Are also not working because, as I said, modsecurity is still tripping for me.

I'm using `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)` and `ModSecurity v3` with the `ModSecurity-apache connector` and `OWASP's CoreRuleSet`

Comment: Assuming your "whitelist" format is correct, it looks like you need to change the `id:` values in your entries to match the mod_security rules you want to bypass. Added answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "rule" ID is set to some date code `20210410001`.

If it is only the two rules you need to whitelist, then you should only need two of those lines.

The "id:" parameter of one should be `953120` and the second "id:" should be `959100`.

Those are the IDs of the rules in the mod_security log you posted.

I may be misinterpreting your rules, and where you are creating them?

To explain, most "whitelisting" in mod_security is done by associating with the `ID` value of the rule you are trying to whitelist.
So `[id "959100"]` is the part of the log line telling you what rule is being invoked.

For example, you could edit the `whitelist.conf`. I am not sure on your install but something like:
`vim /etc/apache2/conf.d/whitelist.conf`
or more likely it is closer to this:

`vim /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_10_whitelist.conf`

(*But wherever your modsec config is*)

Add rules like:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^192\.168\.0\.1" "phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=off,id:959100"
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^192\.168\.0\.1" "phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=off,id:953120"
```

Comment: Oh, I thought I was creating the whitelisting rule and I had to give my rules an ID, I assume I'm just whitelisting my IP for those rules IDs then?
Is there no global "Ignore this IP for everything" kind of rule/option/toggle?

Comment: Ok, my mistake was thinking that the remoteip module was taking care of swapping Cloudflare's IP for the users (and mine) IP, but apparently that's only for logs, if I change `REMOTE_ADDR` to `REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For` it works.